# generalized Teichmüller character

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

On [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_character), the Wikipedia mentions a more general form of Teichmüller character: given a complete discrete valuation ring $\mathcal O$ whose residue field $k$ is perfect of characteristic $p$, there is a unique multiplicative section $\omega: k\to\mathcal O$ of the natural surjection $\mathcal O\to k$. The image of an element under this map is called its Teichmüller representative. The restriction of $\omega$ to $k^\times$ is called the Teichmüller character. I know how to show the existence of the character $\omega$ when the residue field $k$ has finite cardinality, which can also be found in many text books on ANT.
But what about this general case? Could anyone offer any nice reference? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I finally found the answer at Serre's book Local Fields, Chap. II, Proposition 8. Thanks for any help.